# MICE imputation impossibility to use function with()

Tags: r, r-mice

I have a database I imputed several times (28, based of frequency of missing data):

```
newimp<-mice(df1,m=28,seed=1,method='cart')
```

I used method cart because I kept getting this following error: system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.14226e-16.
Thus, using cart I could get through my imputation analysis.

Then with my results I would like to use function with() which analyses each of the my completed datasets separately based on the analysis model I want:

```
modelFit1 <- with(newimp,lm(iupm_yr2~.,data=newimp))
```

trying to get linear regression using as predictors all the variables and outcome the variable called 'yupm_yr2'.
However I get the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"mids"’ to a data.frame
```